# jQuery UI Tabs Styling removing a small space/gap between tabs and content and removing the tabs bottom border roundness

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Ok, I've been playing with the tabs for a bit on an inherited project I am working on, and the styling seems to be working almost fluently with the new tabbed set I am attempting to add however mine seems to have gap of sorts between the tabs themselves and the content below. Which is fine with the exception that the border underneath the tabs doesn't hide so to speak when a tab is selected, nor to the unselected tabs appear to be resting on the same border leaving the illusion of a gap. Worse off, the border has to very small rounded edges point upwards which looks a bit tacky to me and I'd like to fix that too.

Im not sure what classes I have to alter in order to achieve having unselected tabs rest on the border, while the selected tab I assume hovers over the border just enough to cover it giving it the illusion that that piece of border is now missing. Nor do I know which classes I have to alter to make that border stop rounding upwards.

here is a screenshot of what I am talking about to aid in what I am attempting to explain.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tighten up the HTML to remove character space or update the CSS property value, example: display: table-cell;